# Switching between fragments while saving their state (values of variables) [edittexts and textviews]

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I have made a "navigation drawer activity" using Android Studio (kotlin).

On the fragment_home.xml, I have added EditText and Buttons.
On the MainActivity.kt, I have added calculations so that when Button is pressed, results are displayed in TextView on the same fragment_home.

The problem is when i swipe the nav drawer, and change from fragment_home to another fragment, and then come back to the same fragment_home,  the buttons and edittexts do not work at all.

Please help , i am new and looking for a solution for many days.

Basically some values are entered and two buttons are available:
calculate and reset.
Logic is, if any inputtext is empty, it will display message "enter correct value"
and if reset button is tapped, it will reset the values to preset, default values which are float numbers...
The code is below for mainactivity.kt:

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

       //values from editText are imported to variables
    val inputcatload2 = findViewById(R.id.inputcatload1) as EditText
    val inputcatconv2 = findViewById(R.id.inputcatconv1) as EditText
    val inputcfr2 = findViewById(R.id.inputcfr1) as EditText

         //values from Textviews are imported to variables
    val outputcatflow2 = findViewById(R.id.outputcatflow1) as TextView
    val outputdistillateflow2 = findViewById(R.id.outputdistillateflow1) as TextView
    val outputtotalfeed2 = findViewById(R.id.outputtotalfeed1) as TextView
    val outputh1passessv2 = findViewById(R.id.outputh1passessv1) as TextView

         //display of error message and declaration of two buttons
    val msg1 = findViewById(R.id.message1) as TextView
    val btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button1) as Button
    val btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2) as Button


      //if any input is empty, message "enter proper input" is displayed else calculation is done
    btn1.setOnClickListener {
        inputcatload2.text.toString()
        if (inputcatload2.length() == 0 || inputcatload2.text.toString() == ".") {
            val msg2="Please input correct Load"
            msg1.setText(msg2)

        } else if (inputcatconv2.length() == 0 || inputcatconv2.text.toString() == "."){
            val msg2="Please input correct Cat. Conversion"
            msg1.setText(msg2)

        } else if (inputcfr2.length() == 0 || inputcfr2.text.toString() == "."){
            val msg2="Please input correct CFR"
            msg1.setText(msg2)

        } else {
            val msg2="*** RESULTS ***"
            msg1.setText(msg2)

            val val1 = inputcatload2.text.toString().toFloat()
            val val2 = inputcatconv2.text.toString().toFloat()
            val val3 = inputcfr2.text.toString().toFloat()

            val result1 = val1 * 148.72 / 100;
            val rounded1 = String.format("%.2f", result1)
            outputcatflow2.setText(rounded1)

            val result2 = val1 * 148.72/100 * val3;
            val rounded2 = String.format("%.1f", result2)
            outputtotalfeed2.setText(rounded2)


            val result3 = (val1 * 148.72/100 * val3) - (val1 * 148.72/100);
            val rounded3 = String.format("%.2f", result3)
            outputdistillateflow2.setText(rounded3)

            val result4 = (val1 * 148.72/100 * val3)/2;
            val rounded4 = String.format("%.1f", result4)
            outputh1passessv2.setText(rounded4)

        }
    }
         //this is reset button which sets all inputs to default float values
    btn2.setOnClickListener{
        inputcatload2.setText("100")
        inputcatconv2.setText("31.2")
        inputcfr2.setText("1.24")
        msg1.setText("")
        outputcatflow2.setText("")
        outputdistillateflow2.setText("")
        outputtotalfeed2.setText("")
        outputh1passessv2.setText("")
    }



  //everything is unchanged here

    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

    binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Built by Umair Fareed\nFor personal use only. Not to be distributed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
    val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

Comment: please show your code to understand the problem, if you need to preserve the value when switching fragments you need to use show/hide methods, maybe you are using now replace method, and one fragment is replaced with another.

Comment: i have added the code, please have a look at it...

Comment: i'm a little confused, you said that  EditText and Buttons  are at fragment_home,  but you show MainActivity  and there are buttons and other views and how do you open fragments